# How to detect update from play store for expo app?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

I have developed an app in expo. But how to detect the update from google play store?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not yet implemented in `Expo SDK`. It will be available probably in SDK 43. There is also a request open regarding this, check it out [here](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/android-in-app-update)

Comment: any update on this as of 2022?

Comment: Not yet. Let's wait for Expo SDK 46. :)

Comment: No news ? We are near 2024 